# How to wire a set of stand alone Python programs

Tags: python

I have been given a task for eliminating duplicate names in the file below

my.txt:

> "Amazon.com, Inc"
>   AMB Limited
>   Ambac Private
>   amazon inc
>   amb lim
>   ambac pvt

I have done coding in Python for eliminating duplicates in few steps as below (I have done each step in a new Python file):

Step 1: Replacing "Private" with "pvt", "Limited" with "lim" ... etc

Step 2: Removed all special characters and reduced double spaces to single spaces

Step 3: Converted all to lower case

Step 4: Matched and eliminated duplicates

Step 5: Sorted the list in alphabetical order

However, my boss wants me to wire all the programs into a single Python file but I am not familiar with doing this. is there any sample way that you can teach me to wire them up? He wants me to built functions and use content return them.

ex: using `if __name__="__main__"`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a template. You should read some tutorials, too.

```
def foo1():
    return 1

def main():
    ret=foo1()
    print ret

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: it would be nice if you can provide me link of any bigger program !!!

Comment: Try google code search.... But I recommend you: switch of your computer and read a book about python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the template assuming `step1.py`, ..., `step5.py`

```
import step1
import step2
import step3
import step4
import step5

input = get_input() # get input

output_step1 = step1.execute_this_step(input)
output_step2 = step2.execute_this_step(output_step1)
output_step3 = step3.execute_this_step(output_step2)
output_step4 = step4.execute_this_step(output_step3)
output = step5.execute_this_step(output_step4)
```